# Search of an element on a unsorted array recursively

Tags: c, arrays, sorting, search, recursion

This is an exercise that I took from an exam. It asks to write a function that receives an unsorted array `v[]` and a number `X` and the function will return 1 if `X` is present in `v[]` or 0 if `X` is not present in `v[]`. **The function must be recursive** and must work in this manner:

```
 1. Compares X with the element in the middle of v[];
 2. The function calls itself (recursion!!) on upper half and on the lower half of v[];
```

So I've written this function:

```
int occ(int *p,int dim,int X){

    int pivot,a,b;
    pivot=(dim)/2;

    if(dim==0) //end of array
        return 0;

    if(*(p+pivot)==X) //verify if the element in the middle is X
        return 1;

    a=occ(p,pivot,X); //call on lower half
    b=occ(p+pivot,dim-pivot,X); //call on upper half

    if(a+b>=1) //if X is found return 1 else 0
        return 1;
    else{
        return 0;
    }
}
```

I tried to simulated it on a sheet of paper and it *seems* to be correct (Even though I'm not sure) then I've written it on ideone and it can't run the program! 
Here is the link: https://ideone.com/ZwwpAW

Is my code actually wrong (probably!) or is it a problem related to ideone. Can someone help  me? Thank you in advance!!!

Comment: IMHO this method will not work for an `unsorted` array.

Comment: @sjsam Yes it would work fine on a sorted array but the exercise ask me to write a function that deals with a unsorted array so I have to respect the request

Comment: My code doen't even work on a sorted array!

Comment: The implementation looks ok for me so far; what exactly is the problem? are you able to use a debugger on it?

Comment: @Dipok : Or I could be wrong with my first comment. But let it be there.

Comment: @Codor No, I can't use a debugger. I was struggling on finding a mistake on my code.

Comment: If you can use ideone why can't you use a debugger? Using a debugger would be a good way to understand the execution of your program.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is with `b=occ(p+pivot,dim-pivot,X);` when `pivot` is 0. i.e. when `dim` is 1.

the next function call becomes `occ(p,1,X);` This again leads to the call `occ(p,1,X);` in a continuous loop.

It can be fixed by adding a condition to the call, as shown in the code below.

```
int occ(int *p,int dim,int X){

  int pivot,a=0,b=0;
  pivot=(dim)/2;
  if(dim==0){
      return 0;
  }

  if(*(p+pivot)==X)
      return 1;

  if (pivot != 0)
  {
    a=occ(p,pivot,X);
    b=occ(p+pivot,dim-pivot,X);
  }

  if(a+b>=1)
      return 1;
  else{
      return 0;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The implemetation is causing a stack overflow, as the recursion does not terminate if the input contains only one element. This can be fixed as follows.

```
int occ(int *p, int dim, int X)
{
    int pivot, a, b;
        pivot = (dim) / 2;
    if (dim == 0)
    {
        return 0;
    }
    if (*(p + pivot) == X)
    {
        return 1;
    }

    if (dim == 1)
    {
        if (*(p + pivot) == X)
        {
            return 1;
        }
        else
        {
            return 0;
        }
    }

    a = occ(p,         pivot,       X);
    b = occ(p + pivot, dim - pivot, X);
    if (a + b >= 1)
    {
        return 1;
    }
    else
    {
        return 0;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It's enought to change only this one line in the source code to avoid the endless loop with **occ(p,1,X)**:

```
   //if(dim==0) //end of array
   if (pivot == 0)
        return 0;
```